# What is the remote-control batarang for?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

What is the remote control batarang good for in Batman Arkham asylum?

I have so far not been able to find a use for it.

Comment: Oh now I see ... the problem was that I use inverted controls but the control for the batarang didn't get inverted so whatever I did it would end up hitting the floor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's good for taking out distant enemies - snipers are the best example. Also, the remote batarang doesn't stop when colliding with enemies, only with walls and such; so with a little practice it's possible to steer it so that you could bring down multiple enemies in one throw.

Notice that enemies aware of the batarang will try to evade it.

Answer (score 10):

- Hit enemies around the corner
- Knock down enemies that are hard to reach
- The batarang will also give you some info about the enemies within a room since the camera will follow the item

Personally I've used it in stealth situations when it was best to not cause a racket.

Answer (score 5):

On the PS3 there is a trophy for catching your own batarang which I got using the remote control batarang. I'm not sure it's possible using the normal batarang.

Answer (score 4):

One of the silent predator challenge maps requires that you take down three enemies with one batarang. I believe you can only do this with the remote batarang. If you want to get 100% and/or get all trophies, you'll need it.

I never used it during normal gameplay, however.  You can definitely just beat the game without it.